# Cannot navigate tabs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>collapsible demo</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<section id="page1" data-role="page">
<header data-role="header">
<h3 style="color:#3CF">Astrophoto Tool</h3>


<nav data-role="navbar">
<ul>
<a href="#rul" class="ui-btn-active">Rule 600</a>
<a href="#at">Advanced Tool</a>
<a href="#hlp">Help</a>
<a href="#abt">About</a>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div id="#rul" data-role="content">
 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <form action="">Lens: Focal  Length (mm)
            <br>
            <input type='text' id='lens' style="color:#FF6"/>
            <br>Full Frame: (Time in Seconds)
            <br>
            <input type='text' id='fullframe' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly>
            <br>APS-C (Canon): (Time in Seconds)
            <br>
            <input type='text' id='apsccanon'  value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
            <br>APS - C (Nikon/Sony/Pentax): (Time in Seconds)
            <br>
            <input type='text' id='apscnikon' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
            <br>APS - C (Olympus/Panasonic): (Time in Seconds)
             <input type='text' id='apscolympus' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />


            <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<section>
<div id="#abt" data-role="content">
 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
<p> About</p>
</div>
</div>
</section>


</div>
</div>
<footer data-role="footer">
<h3>Footer</h3>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Cannot navigate tabs. All the tabs simply displays the content of the first tab. Obviously I'm making a mistake in 'div id'. Cannot figure out how to rectify this. I need help to resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a name="rul"></a>
<div id="rul" data-role="content">
```

Also note that you don't include the "#" when using `id=`. The "#" basically means id.

Also, if you're using `<div id="rul" data-role="content">` just as an anchor link, you can probably remove this all together.

Comment: The above is missing a ". Should be `<a name="abt"></a>`

Comment: Not working even after this:<a name="abt"></a>
<div id="#abt" data-role="content">
 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
<p> About</p>

Comment: Did this. Same result no navigation: <a name="abt"></a>
<p> About</p>
</div>

Comment: Just to clarify...you have this somewhere on the page: `<a href="#at">Advanced Tool</a>`

And later in your code, you have the following `<a name="abt"></a>`.

When you click on Advanced Tool, you aren't jumped down to the section where you have the `<a name="abt"></a>`? True?

Comment: No. The tabs simply don't work. I'm stuck with the first tab 'Rule 600'.

Comment: See here: your exact code, but with my `<a name>` suggestion. Try clicking "Help" and you'll see it jump all the way down to that section: https://jsfiddle.net/jonmrich/Ln23qmnr/

Comment: @jonmrich, I think the OP is using the jQuery Mobile framework and more specifically its tabs widget: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to comment that you should have li items inside the ul list. Like so:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#rul" class="ui-btn-active">Rule 600</a></li>
 <li><a href="#at">Advanced Tool</a></li>
 <li><a href="#hlp">Help</a></li>
 <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Added <li></li> tags. Still cannot navigate.

Comment: Because you still have errors in your code. As the other user pointed out: remove # from <div id="#abt" data-role="content">.

Comment: Corrected. But still not working: <a name="abt"></a>
<div id="abt" data-role="content">
 <div data-role="content">
<p> About</p>

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the **[tabs demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/tabs/)** on the jQM site, you can see how the markup should be structured.

Your page has several issues with elements not being closed properly. As the others have mentioned, the links in the tab list need to be within LI elements. The ids of the tab content divs must not include the '#' character. These should only be in the link HREF.  The tab list and content should all be within a DIV with data-role="tabs".

Try something like this:

```
<section id="page1" data-role="page">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h3 style="color:#3CF">Astrophoto Tool</h3>
    </header>    
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">        
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#rul" class="ui-btn-active">Rule 600</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#at">Advanced Tool</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#hlp">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#abt">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="rul" >
                 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                  </div>
            </div>                               
            <div id="at" >
                 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                    Advanced tool
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hlp" >
                 <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                    Help
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="abt" >
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
                    <p>About</p>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer data-role="footer">
        <h3>Footer</h3>
    </footer>
</section>
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jjfn5n9r/)**

NOTE: if you really want the tab bar in the header section, you can do this with a little script that shows and hides the tabs:

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/K9S4w/2/)**

Comment: This code do not display the result: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pix,#lens,#dec").on("keyup", function () {
    var pix  = $(this).val();
    var lens = $(this).val();
 var dec  = $(this).val();
 var res  = (14*pix*2)/lens*cos((dec/180)*22/7);
 $('#res').val(res.toFixed(2));
    });
});
</script>